# how can I add one item over and over in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

I am trying to make a list that records every pressed key and adds it to a list but when I am trying to append it it only changes the last item to the last pressed key

```
import keyboard

Keys = []
Keys.append(keyboard.read_key())
print(Keys)
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Edit the question.

Comment: Put the last two lines in a loop with `while True:`

Answer (score 1):

You will want to continuously call the second last lines in a loop, e.g.:

```py
import keyboard

Keys = []
while True:
    Keys.append(keyboard.read_key())
    print(Keys)
```

However, this detects both key press and key release! For example, typing `hey` outputs the following:

```py
['h']
['h', 'h']
['h', 'h', 'e']
['h', 'h', 'e', 'e']
['h', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'y']
['h', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'y', 'y']
```

Instead of the `read_key` approach, I would advise using `keyboard.record()` instead, as that seems to be specifically aimed at recording keyboard inputs ([documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.record)). This function also has support for e.g. `until="esc"`, to specify when to stop recording.

Comment: Is `read_key` blocking? How would it ever end?

Comment: Yes, it is blocking. a `KeyboardInterrupt` (Ctrl+C) will end it. I advise against using `read_key` for the purpose of recording keystrokes.

Comment: Thx for your answer it is working great